# Display the result by selection each column from a html table using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, excel

Is it possible to have filtering option in each column of html table in which the data is fetched from mysql as we do in excel sheet?

```
<html>
<?php
    // connect to the database
    include('connect-db.php');

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM log WHERE type='c' ") ;
    echo "<div style='height:auto;'><table border='0' cellpadding='10' class='table table-striped table-bordered'>";
    echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Date</th> <th>Type</th> <th>Batch name</th> <th>No.of Pages</th> <th>User</th><th>file</th><th>Status</th><th></th><th></th></tr>";


    // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
        $id=$row['batch_file'];
        // echo out the contents of each row into a table
        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['assdate'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['type'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'.substr($row['batch_file'], 0, -4).'</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['no_pages'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['assign'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td><a href="copy_test_uploads/'.$row['batch_file'].'"target="_blank"><img src="pdf.png" style=width:35px;></td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['status'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td><a href="controllogviewedit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
        echo '<td><a href="controllogviewdelete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
        echo "</tr>"; 

    } 

    // close table>
    echo "</table></div>";
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using obsolete mysql_* functions?

Comment: I recommend you to give a try to http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html `jQuery DataTables - Individual column searching (select inputs)`, you will be writing less code and developing faster. Besides, DataTables is awesome.

Comment: @Synchro.I am totaly new for development. Php is the first thing I develop.I dont knw the do's and dont's of it.I concentrate on the functionality for what I expect now. I want to know is it possible to filter a html table as in Excel.As it the requirement to do. I am not sure whether is it possible or not.If its possible please give a simple example for serverside filtering.

Comment: @Kstro21.Thank u for recommending me the link.But unfortunately I am not able to use it.As I need serverside filtering.